# IIS/ASP Redirect a domain to another, both having the same source

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

I have to redirect a domain to another, tricky part being the new domain uses the source of the old one as a host. Implicitly, if I did a general redirect, it would loop and 500 Internal Error.

Grabbed my .htaccess guns to get ready for war only to find that the server is not linux and it uses asp. I've read a bit, accessed the web.config file and the default ruleset is this (which I assume is pretty much standard-issue)

```
<rewrite>

            <rules>

              <rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true"> 

               <match url="(.*)default" /> 

               <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 

              </rule> 

            </rules>

        </rewrite>
```

Is there any way I can do a conditional that checks the domain name and only if the rule matches, it redirects? Something like:

```
<rules>
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)oldDomain.com" />
<action type="Redirect" url="(.*)newdomain.com$" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
</rules>
```

// Actual domain and testing

```
<rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="(.*)intermedcasasibiu\.ro$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}intermedcasasibiu.ro/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Which outputs :

http://intermedcasa.ro/intermedcasasibiu.ro/intermedcasasibiu.ro/intermedcasasibiu.ro/intermedcasasibiu.ro/intermedcasasibiu.ro/AndSoOn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
<rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="(.*)newdomain\.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}newdomain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Apart from that, If you are more familiar with htaccess rewrite rules, you can import them into IIS, check [this guide](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules)

Comment: Thanks Uriil, I'll give it a go in a few minutes and will return with some feedback. Also, a world of thanks for the htaccess import possibility, will definetely go for that option future-based, since I can't currently afford the time to pick up on IIS. Again, a world of thanks!

Comment: I've included in the edit the actual site I`m working on:

@Uriil
The output is a loop of the sort:

http://intermedcasa.ro/intermedcasasibiu.ro/intermedcasasibiu.ro/intermedcasasibiu.ro/intermedcasasibiu.ro[...]